# what is the efficient way of retrieving constantly changing counts from database

Tags: mysql, solr, redis

We are developing a messaging app in which there will be a post which can be liked.The post will be retrieved using solr.I want to retrieve like counts. 
The counts will be changing constantly.What will be the best way to handle the frequent updates in solr?What will be the best option to store these counts and retrieve them instantly?

options 
Mysql + solr using atomic updates and soft commits or
Mysql + solr + redis

Comment: what did you tried by now? can you provide us with some code?

Comment: I'd recommend using redis for this as its `incrby` function is great for any kind of incremental counter - and is mostly atomic (within a margin of error - given special scenarios) across a cluster.

Comment: If you're building a new system, would better use redis for such king of "quick" counters. but if you already have your software working and have mysql +  solr, I will not add redis only for this function at first. I will perform solr facets query in order to retrieve my counter from live datas indexed (Since adding a new componant in a software, adds always complexity and bugs).